# Using VLOOKUP to return values from multiple columns in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Okay so I know this is terribly incorrect. I get a syntax error.
But I'm trying to find a better way to do this in general.
I want to match order numbers to order numbers in another sheet and get all the data from there into my current sheet.

```
Sub Lookup()
On Error Resume Next

For Each row In Worksheets("batches").Range("B4:B1384")
    Result = Application.evaluate("VLOOKUP(row, Worksheets("OrderLvl").Range("C4:DL1384"),{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116}, FALSE)")

If Result = "Error 2042" Then
    'nothing found
End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't indicate what you want to do with the data, but I'd suggest using `Match` instead:

```
Sub Lookup()

    For Each Row In Worksheets("batches").Range("B4:B1384")
        result = Application.Match(Row.Value, Worksheets("OrderLvl").Range("C4:C1384"), 0)

        If Not IsError(result) Then
            Worksheets("OrderLvl").Range("E4:E1384").Cells(result).Resize(, 114).Copy
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: can you explain this method a little bit, I'm not sure if I'm following. and when I tried to run it nothing happened, none of the data actually copied over. The ranges seem to be correct.

Comment: You didn't specify where the data should be pasted so I only showed the `Copy` line as an example. It won't actually do anything without a destination or a a `Paste` line.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the vlookup, i would suggest using range types here like this:

```
Dim LookUpRange As Range
Dim row As Range

Set LookUpRange = Worksheets("batches").Range("B4:B1384")

Result = Application.evaluate("VLOOKUP(" & row.row() & "," & LookUpRange & "," & I &",FALSE)")
```

and push this into a loop that goes over the host of columns you need to take data from, using I for "{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116}, "

Comment: so two loops in total? One going through the columns and one going through the rows?

Comment: yeah, you got it right.
`for I = 3 to 116`
`Next I`